# How to Visualize Concurrent Open Transactions

Tags: bigdata, visualization

I have a large csv data file with over 5 million records. It contains Date Time Begin and Date Time Ended.
Here is an example of what the data looks like

```
2019-08-06 16:07:25,2019-08-06 16:07:42
2019-08-06 17:21:42,2019-08-06 17:21:59
2019-08-06 15:43:03,2019-08-06 15:43:20
2019-08-06 13:48:13,2019-08-06 13:48:30
2019-08-06 16:18:56,2019-08-06 16:19:13
2019-08-06 14:34:10,2019-08-06 14:34:27
2019-08-06 16:59:47,2019-08-06 17:00:04
2019-08-06 16:14:57,2019-08-06 16:15:14
2019-08-06 13:04:38,2019-08-06 13:04:55
2019-08-06 16:09:28,2019-08-06 16:09:45
```

My goal is to be able to visualize the data to be identify at what times has the highest active concurrent connections. Ideally the more narrow the time interval we are able to look at the better. The data is dated between 2 months.

Can anyone suggest an approach I can use to tackle this?

I have tried using Python to loop through the entire file for each record to identify how many concurrent connections there were. It worked well when I did a small scale test with a few thousand records. But with a file that has over 5 million records, that approach won't work well because it will take quite a while to loop through all 5 million records, 5 million times each.

Answer (score 1):

I address only the central problem how to *transform your data to show the degree of parallelism of the transactions*.

I use (Oracle) SQL to demonstrate the idea.

Let's assume this is your data

```
select * from tab;

START_DT            END_DT             
------------------- -------------------
06.08.2019 16:07:25 06.08.2019 16:07:42
06.08.2019 16:07:30 06.08.2019 16:07:35
06.08.2019 16:07:33 06.08.2019 16:07:50
06.08.2019 16:07:50 06.08.2019 16:07:55
```

In the first step you split each row in two parts (using `UNION ALL`)

The first part identify  the *start of the transaction* will **increase** the *count of active transaction by 1*.

The second part identify  the *end of the transaction* will **decrease** the *count of active transaction by 1*.

As a timestamp you use either the start or end day of the transaction.

```
select start_dt trans_dt ,1 trans_cnt from tab union all
select end_dt trans_dt ,-1 trans_cnt from tab
order by 1;

TRANS_DT             TRANS_CNT
------------------- ----------
06.08.2019 16:07:25          1
06.08.2019 16:07:30          1
06.08.2019 16:07:33          1
06.08.2019 16:07:35         -1
06.08.2019 16:07:42         -1
06.08.2019 16:07:50          1
06.08.2019 16:07:50         -1
06.08.2019 16:07:55         -1
```

Having the date so prepared you need only to **accumulate**  the transaction count, which is done by aggregated function `SUM` in the analytic from ordered on the transaction timestamp. More to that later.

Finally you consolidates the case where more than one transaction starts or ends in a same timestamp - you use `GROUP BY` and `MAX` parallel degree.

The full query

```
with trans as (
select start_dt trans_dt ,1 trans_cnt from tab union all
select end_dt trans_dt ,-1 trans_cnt from tab),
trans_cum as (
select trans_dt,trans_cnt,
   sum(trans_cnt) over (order by trans_dt, trans_cnt) parallel_trans_cnt
from trans)
select trans_dt, max(parallel_trans_cnt) parallel_trans_cnt
from trans_cum
group by trans_dt
order by 1;
```

result

```
TRANS_DT            PARALLEL_TRANS_CNT
------------------- ------------------
06.08.2019 16:07:25                  1
06.08.2019 16:07:30                  2
06.08.2019 16:07:33                  3
06.08.2019 16:07:35                  2
06.08.2019 16:07:42                  1
06.08.2019 16:07:50                  1
06.08.2019 16:07:55                  0
```

This data can be simple visualized with an ordinary x,y plot.

Some care should be taken is one transaction ends in the same second as the next start.
Were at this second two transaction active or only one?

The query above assumes the latter case, if you want to consider the former case simple adjust the *accumulation logic* to

```
sum(trans_cnt) over (order by trans_dt, trans_cnt DESC) parallel_trans_cnt
```

Within the same second you will first consider the starting transaction (which will increase the parallel degree) and than the ending transactions.

You may implement this logic in any programming language, but note that **SQL** 1) is very concise, 2)  you are not limited with the main memory and 3) you have parallel processing out of the box.